# How to run SQL server 2012 instead of 2014 when both are installed and 2014 is currently running?

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I need to backup a DB using SQL server 2012 to match another server it is going to.  However on my local machine I'm currently running 2014.  I can see that SQL server 2012 is installed along with various other versions.  How can I change which version is running from 2014 to 2012?

Comment: You can run multiple versions and instances of SQL Server concurrently. If both SQL Server 2012 and 2014 are installed then one is a default instance and the other is a named instance... or they're both named instances. You need to connect to the appropriate instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll give that a go cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the database in question is on a 2014 instance the backup can't be restored to an earlier version. You can't get a earlier format backup from a newer version.